Options to enforce a logical constraint in an Oracle database
Suppose I have a pair of tables, A and B, that are in a standard one to many relationship, with B containing a foreign key to A. I’d like to introduce a table C with a many-to-many relationship to B, but with the restriction that, for any given record in C, all of the associated records in B are associated with a single record in A. A simple link table between C and B provides the desired many-to-many relationship, but it does nothing to prevent a single record in C from being associated with B's tied to different A's. The only way I can think of accomplishing this in the database is to create a trigger to check and enforce the condition. Are there other applicable techniques?

I suggest adding some sample data to your question.

You may have no choice but to denormalize reference to a into your c table, as MT0 demonstrates. But this may be an indication that there's a problem in the data model that needs rethinking.

Thank you. It's hard for me to judge whether this need to denormalize is really a problem, and unfortunately I'm not free to reveal the actual data or requirements to get input from others on that point. That said, it seems likely that we may want to list out all C's for a particular A without even considering B, so this would be another (small) benefit of the denormalization.

Include the primary key for table a in tables b, c and in the bridging table used to define the many-to-many relationship between b and c:
CREATE TABLE a (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE b (
  id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  a_id REFERENCES a (id),
  UNIQUE (id, a_id)
);

CREATE TABLE c (
  id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  a_id REFERENCES a(id),
  UNIQUE (id, a_id)
);

CREATE TABLE bc_bridge (
  a_id,
  b_id,
  c_id,
  FOREIGN KEY (a_id, b_id) REFERENCES b (a_id, id),
  FOREIGN KEY (a_id, c_id) REFERENCES c (a_id, id)
);

Then table c can be related to many bs (and vice-versa) but related rows in those tables are always only related to a single a.

You can use a constraint on a materialized view to enforce the conditions.
If you have the tables a, b, c with a bridging table representing the many-to-many relationship between b and c:
CREATE TABLE a (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE b (
  id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  a_id REFERENCES a (id),
  UNIQUE (id, a_id)
);

CREATE TABLE c (
  id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE bc_bridge (
  b_id REFERENCES b (id),
  c_id REFERENCES c (id)
);

Then you can create a materialized view that finds the minimum and maximum a values for each c:
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON bc_bridge
   WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID(b_id, c_id)
   INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON b
   WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID(id, a_id)
   INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW bc_min_max_a_mv
   BUILD IMMEDIATE
   REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
   AS SELECT bc.c_id,
             MIN(b.a_id) AS a_min,
             MAX(b.a_id) AS a_max
      FROM   bc_bridge bc,
             b
      WHERE  b.id = bc.b_id
      GROUP BY bc.c_id;

And use a constraint on the materialized view to enforce that the minimum and maximum a values should be the same.
ALTER TABLE bc_min_max_a_mv ADD CHECK( a_min = a_max );

(Note: Untested, but it should give you the general idea.)

Thank you for both answers! I'm still digesting the second one, but the first seems perfect. I appreciate your taking the time to lay it out so clearly.

INNER JOIN in MV with RFRESH FAST ON COMMIT may not work on older Oracle versions then use old style JOIN: "...FROM bc_bridge bc, b WHERE b.id = bc.b_id..."

Anyway the DISTINCT is blocking even in 23ai.

A solution is to use LISTAGG(DISTINCT b.a_id, ',' ) (req. version >= 19c) which is accepted by the REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT and then the constraint could be written as INSTR of ',' returns 0.

@p3consulting Updated the join condition and updated the query to compare MIN(a_id) = MAX(a_id) as I have a slight preference for that to converting the values to strings - but your way would work too (unless the ids are strings and can contain commas when a different delimiter would be needed).

@MTO Well LISTAGG(DISTINCT) is accepted at the creation of the MV but in fact the refresh is not happening, probably a bug here (23ai)
